# DateTimePicker manipulation

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker

I am trying to manipulate the value of the datetimepicker with a textchange event..

```
private void txtStay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker2.Text = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(txtStay.Text)).ToString();
}
```

but I'm having trouble when i press the backspace to change the value in the textbox, it causing an error. what i want to happen is that, when i press the backspace, it will change value of the date with the remaining number in the text.

Comment: What is the exception you are facing with that ? also, Why are you setting the text property of DateTimePicker instead of setting value directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your final purpose, but to resolve value error add following code in event;

```
        int days=0;
        Int32.TryParse(txtStay.Text, out days);
        dateTimePicker2.Text = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(days);
```

it should work.

But you should not add days with reference to any of fix days not the current date of date picker.

I mean it will keep on adding days if you change values in textbox..!!

---------EDIT---------

TO get the correct date use this;

```
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(days);
```

Above it take current date as base date, but it likes you will have to take your dateTimepicker1(start date) as base date.

Comment: tnx sir..i already solved the error..my problem now is that..how to decrement the days whenever i hit the backspace. lets say, from the textbOX..i input 12, the days will increment to days,but if i press the backspace to remove the '2' from 12..the days well decrement and will only add 1 day..